# Renumbering table caption

Tags: tables, captions

There are two tables first. First two tables are numbered as Table-1 and Table-2.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{amsthm}  
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2061}{} 
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{8289}{}
\begin{document}  
\begin{table}[h]
        \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
                \hline
                $\wedge$ &$\phi$ &$\{a\}$ &$\{b\}$ &$\{a,b\}$\\
                \hline
                $\phi$ & $\phi$ &$\phi$ &$\phi$ &$\phi$\\
                \hline
                $a$ &$\phi$ &\{a\} &$\phi$ &$\{a\}$\\
                \hline
                $b$ &$\phi$ &$\phi$ &$\{b\}$ &$\{b\}$ \\
                \hline
                $\{a,b\}$ &$\phi$ &$\{a\}$ &$\{b\}$ &$\{a,b\}$ \\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \caption{Composition table for meet}
        \end{center}
    \end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            $\vee$ &$\phi$ &$\{a\}$ &$\{b\}$ &$\{a,b\}$\\
            \hline
            $\phi$ & $\phi$ &$\{a\}$ &$\{b\}$ &$\{a,b\}$\\
            \hline
            $a$ &$\{a\}$ &$\{a\}$ &$\{a,b\}$ &$\{a,b\}$\\
            \hline
            $b$ &$\{b\}$ &$\{a,b\}$ &$\{b\}$ &$\{a,b\}$ \\
            \hline
            $\{a,b\}$ &$\{a,b\}$ &$\{a,b\}$ &$\{a,b\}$ &$\{a,b\}$ \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Composition table for join}
    \end{center}
\end{minipage}
    \end{table}
**After some texts, 3rd table begins...**
\begin{table}[h!]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{c|cccc}
            $w'x'y'z$ &$0$ &$0$ &$0$ &$1$\\
            $w'x'yz'$ & $0$ &$0$ &$1$ &$0$ \\ \hline
            $w'x'yz$ &$0$ &$0$ &$1$ &$1$ \\
            $wx'yz'$ &$1$ &$0$ &$1$ &$0$ \\
            $wxy'z'$ &$1$ &$1$ &$0$ &$0$ \\ \hline
            $wx'yz$ &$1$ &$0$ &$1$ &$1$ \\
            $wxyz'$ &$1$ &$1$ &$1$ &$0$ \\   
        \end{tabular}
    \caption{$$}
    \end{center}
\end{table}  
\end{document}
```

But then I want to rename the 3rd table as Table-1 which is not happening. Any suggestion would be appreciable.

A warning is showing: '**Functionality similar to this package has recently(everypage) been implemented in LaTeX. This package is now in(everypage) legacy status**.'

Comment: Do you have any other tables within the document? If not, then you can merely do `\setcounter{table}{0}` before this third table.

Comment: @Werner when I put `\caption{Table-1}`, it is appearing as **Table 1: Table-1**

Comment: I just want to have Table-1 and nothing else with it as a caption.

Comment: I wondering why you like to have such strange tables numbering. To my opinion it make only confusion in table implicit or explicit referencing. I will never do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the [`caption`package](//ctan.org/pkg/caption) to manage caption formatting:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}  

\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{namedash}{#1-#2}
\captionsetup[table]{labelformat=namedash}

\begin{document} 

\begin{table}[htb]
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ | *{5}{c |} }
      \hline
      $\wedge$  & $\phi$ & $\{a\}$ & $\{b\}$ & $\{a,b\}$  \\
      \hline
      $\phi$    & $\phi$ & $\phi$  & $\phi$ & $\phi$      \\
      \hline
      $a$       & $\phi$ & $\{a\}$ & $\phi$ & $\{a\}$     \\
      \hline
      $b$       & $\phi$ & $\phi$ & $\{b\}$ & $\{b\}$     \\
      \hline
      $\{a,b\}$ & $\phi$ & $\{a\}$ & $\{b\}$ & $\{a,b\}$ \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Composition table for meet}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ | *{5}{c |} }
      \hline
      $\vee$    & $\phi$    & $\{a\}$   & $\{b\}$   & $\{a,b\}$ \\
      \hline
      $\phi$    & $\phi$    & $\{a\}$   & $\{b\}$   & $\{a,b\}$ \\
      \hline
      $a$       & $\{a\}$   & $\{a\}$   & $\{a,b\}$ & $\{a,b\}$ \\
      \hline
      $b$       & $\{b\}$   & $\{a,b\}$ & $\{b\}$   & $\{a,b\}$ \\
      \hline
      $\{a,b\}$ & $\{a,b\}$ & $\{a,b\}$ & $\{a,b\}$ & $\{a,b\}$ \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Composition table for join}
  \end{minipage}
\end{table}

**After some texts, 3rd table begins...**

\begin{table}[htb]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ c | *{4}{c} }
    $w'x'y'z$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ & $1$ \\
    $w'x'yz'$ & $0$ & $0$ & $1$ & $0$ \\
    \hline
    $w'x'yz$  & $0$ & $0$ & $1$ & $1$ \\
    $wx'yz'$  & $1$ & $0$ & $1$ & $0$ \\
    $wxy'z'$  & $1$ & $1$ & $0$ & $0$ \\
    \hline
    $wx'yz$   & $1$ & $0$ & $1$ & $1$ \\
    $wxyz'$   & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $0$
  \end{tabular}
  \caption*{Table-1}
\end{table}  

\end{document}
```

This allows you to use `\caption*` to have an unformatted caption (just the text), where you can place whatever you want.

Comment: one can also reset table counter ```\setcounter{table}{0}``` or instead of ```0``` to ```n-1```. Use it before table you want to alter.